# Cloned router-link should load on child router-view but it also reloads main reouter-view

Tags: jquery, datatables, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I have a problem regarding VueJS with vue-router and datatables.net.
What I want to achieve is to get edit buttons in my datatable for each entery. To do this I first create an object in template for example:

```
<div class="copy btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group" aria-label="Actions">
  <router-link to="pricelist/edit/" class="btn btn-default">edit</router-link>
</div>
```

Now I use jQuery dataTable to which I send data through self created Vue component and as a last column I use action buttons such as edit. To recreate them in table I use:

```
data () {
  columnDefs: [
        {
          targets: [6],
          orderable: false,
          searchable: false,
          data: null,
          render: function (data, type, row) {
            var dom = $('.copy').clone(true, true)
            dom.children()[0].href += row.id
            return $(dom[0]).html()
          }
        }
  ]
}
```

which displays the button, but when I click on it it also reloads main view, not only inner . But if I put the same link in the menu it work as expected; That means opening new route in inner router-view without reloading the main view.
If it makes difference I also use named router-view

Why does it not work when I do it from buttons rendered in data()?

Thank you for you help!

routes.js:

```
path: '/admin',
component: require('./components/admin/admin.vue'),
meta: {},
children: [
  {
    path: 'codelists/pricelist',
    meta: {menu: ['codelists', 'pricelist'], auth: true},
    components: {default: require('./components/admin/codelists/pricelist/list.vue')},
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add',
        meta: {menu: ['codelists', 'pricelist'], auth: true},
        components: {overlay: require('./components/admin/codelists/pricelist/new.vue')}
      },
      {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        meta: {menu: ['codelists', 'pricelist'], auth: true},
        components: {overlay: require('./components/admin/codelists/pricelist/edit.vue')},
        props: { default: true, overlay: true }
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

menu.js from where it works as expected:

```
codelists: {
  icon: 'save',
  title: 'Šifranti',
  link: '/admin/codelists/brands',
  elements: {
    pricelist: {
      icon: 'folder',
      title: 'Cenik',
      link: '/admin/codelists/pricelist',
      elements: {addNew: {icon: 'add', title: 'Dodaj', link: 'pricelist/edit/154'}}
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Perhaps I could attach eventHandler from router-link to

```
<a href="'pricelist/edit/' + row.id" class="btn btn-default">edit</a>
```

But I haven't fount it so I could copy it... Has anyone done it like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with extending fnDrawCallback to the ocmponent from datatables.net.
Than I just rebinded programmatic route like:

```
columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: [3],
        orderable: false,
        searchable: false,
        data: null,
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          return '' +
            '<div id="' + row.id + '" class="edit btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group" aria-label="Actions">' +
            '<a type="button" class="btn btn-default">edit</a>' +
            '</div>'
        }
      }
    ],
    fnDrawCallback: function (oSettings, vue) {
      $('.edit', this).unbind('click')
      $('.edit', this).click(function () {
        vue.$router.push({path: 'units/edit/' + this.id})
      })
    },
```